# Can you Zillean ulti a yourick zombie?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If Mordakaiser's, Zilean's, and Yorick's ults are placed on a champion, in what order do the ults take place?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/if-mordakaisers-zileans-and-yoricks-ults-are-placed-on-a-champion-in-what)

Or vice-versa; does it just not activate or does it actually work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Zilean can ulti a Zombie, but the Ulti is wasted since hey cannot revive from being a Reverent.

Comment: so it's better to zill ulti then yourick ulti?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot revive a yorick zombie. If you ult the original person in question, zilean's ultimate takes precedence. The revenant will remain when you die, allowing you to revive. If you die again afterwards, THEN the revenant will take your place.