# A Yorick problem!

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If Mordakaiser's, Zilean's, and Yorick's ults are placed on a champion, in what order do the ults take place?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/if-mordakaisers-zileans-and-yoricks-ults-are-placed-on-a-champion-in-what)

what whould happen if Yorick was dying and he ulted on himself while he had Guardian Angel active and meanwhile Zilean ulted on him too?

Answer (score 2):

The order of operation would be:

Zilean's Chronoshift would activate first, reviving him.

Then if he dies again, Guardian Angel would revive him.

And if by chance he dies *again* before Omen of Death's 10 second duration is over, he will be reactivated (even though it will now officially count as a death).

Answer (score -1):

1. First the Zil ultimate will revieve him
2. The Yorick ultimate will revieve him
3. The GA will revieve him