# What is the order of any type of "resurrection" in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that there are several types of resurrection skills in LoL. What do I mean by the "**resurrection**" term?

Following skills and items can be categorized under the term "resurrection":

- Champion Passive - Aatrox Passive
- Item - Guardian Angel
- Champion Skill - Yorick - Ulti
- Champion Skill -Zilean - Ulti

To combine all of this, all of the other skills and items should be used on Aatrox. I'm just curious about what order these skills will take effect?
Assuming;

- Skills used just before first death
- There is continuous damage that is applied on the champion Aatrox (say 3k true damage per second)

With above assumption what will happen? Has anybody ever tried this?

*Note: If I forgot to mention any skill, passive or item that resurrects the applied champion please indicate them, too.*

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57914/18146 dup http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86401/18146 sans new champs like aatrox/zac

Comment: Those posts didn't have any comment about Aatrox/Zac when I asked this question. Thus, I don't believe it is duplicated.

Comment: well,we discussed it under the comment section. He assumed Aatrox's passive is same as Anivia's egg. After a discussion, figured out that he was right, and accepted his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not *know* how Aatrox fits into this, but I *assume* it is the same as Anivia's egg and the order goes as follows, from first to last:

- Zilean's ultimate
- Guardian Angel
- Anivia's egg (I assume Aatrox's passive works the same)
- Yorick's ultimate
- Afterlife abilities (Karthus and Zyra's passives)

Also found this interesting [thread on the subject from the LoL forums.](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=593055)

Tested on August 5th 2013.

There's also [another answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86432/51318) that covers this quite well.

Comment: This is most likely correct, as Zac also works this way. Yorick's ability doesn't prevent death, so it always has bottom priority.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I know that Anivia turns to egg when she reaches 0 health, same as Zac. But, how about Aatrox, does he reach 0 health against a fatal damage or passive becomes active before reaching 0 health? If second option is true, does this change the order?

Comment: @shyos It could change the order, and quite frankly, I'm not sure where Aatrox fits in the picture. I haven't played that actively since Zac came out and that was a good while ago. I'll have to try it out.

Comment: @3ventic Nevermind. I guess it is the same with Anivia and Zac. Logically, since passive also provides attack speed to Aatrox, GA should be used first. Otherwise, it frees the passive bar and wastes all that attack speed.